# Directed Acyclic Graph : Updating the vertex property of a parent node by comparing the property of the child nodes.

Tags: c++, boost, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the connections between nodes in a DAG like this.

```
1 --> 7
2 -->
3 --> 4 5
4 --> 6
5 --> 
6 --> 
7 -->
```

I have to perform some tasks on this graph.
1) Find all the vertices without successors.
2) Assign a value to the vertices without successors. (I can do this with Vertex properties).
3) Back trace the graph and update all the parent node (Even the intermediate parent node) at each level with the minimum value of the children.

For example,

As per the above DAG, Vertices {2,5,6,7} are without any successors or out edges.
Assume I will assign values {3,2,4,6} to vertices {2,5,6,7} respectively.

Since Vertex 4 is the parent node to 5 and 6, I have to add the value min{2,4} = 2 to Vertex 4.
Similarly, 1 is the parent node to 7. So I have to add the value 6 to node 1.

May I know which functions I can use for each step so that the "Search" time is minimal.

I also wanted to know, is something above mentioned possible in a DAG using boost.

Comment: You need to write some code, then you can ask about it.  SO is not a code writing site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fun:

> I have the connections between nodes in a DAG like this.

```
using G = boost::adjacency_list<>;
G g(8);
add_edge(1, 7, g);
add_edge(3, 4, g);
add_edge(3, 5, g);
add_edge(4, 6, g);
```

> Assume I will assign values {3,2,4,6} to vertices {2,5,6,7} respectively.

```
auto p = boost::make_vector_property_map<int>(id);
p[2] = 3; p[5] = 2; p[6] = 4; p[7] = 6;
```

> 3) Back trace the graph [...]

```
std::vector<V> order;
topological_sort(g, back_inserter(order));
```

> [...] and update all the parent node (Even the intermediate parent node) at each level with the minimum value of the children.

```
auto getter = [&p](V vd) { return p[vd]; };
for (V vd : order) {
    auto child = make_iterator_range(adjacent_vertices(vd, g));
    if (child.size())
        p[vd] += *min_element(child | transformed(std::cref(getter)));
}
```

You didn't specify it but you will probably want to see the result:

```
print_graph(g, boost::make_transform_value_property_map(
                [&](V vd) { return "vertex #" + std::to_string(vd) + " (" + std::to_string(p[vd]) + ")"; }, id
            ));
```

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4ceca5ffba88739)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/min_element.hpp>

using boost::adaptors::transformed;

int main() {
    using G = boost::adjacency_list<>;
    using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
    /*
     *1 --> 7
     *2 -->
     *3 --> 4 5
     *4 --> 6
     *5 --> 
     *6 --> 
     *7 -->
     */
    G g(8);
    add_edge(1, 7, g);
    add_edge(3, 4, g);
    add_edge(3, 5, g);
    add_edge(4, 6, g);

    // {3,2,4,6} to vertices {2,5,6,7}
    auto id = get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    auto p = boost::make_vector_property_map<int>(id);
    p[2] = 3; p[5] = 2; p[6] = 4; p[7] = 6;

    std::vector<V> order;
    boost::topological_sort(g, back_inserter(order));

    auto getter = [&p](V vd) { return p[vd]; };
    for (V vd : order) {
        auto child = make_iterator_range(adjacent_vertices(vd, g));
        if (child.size())
            p[vd] += *min_element(child | transformed(std::cref(getter)));
    }

    print_graph(g, boost::make_transform_value_property_map(
                    [&](V vd) { return "vertex #" + std::to_string(vd) + " (" + std::to_string(p[vd]) + ")"; },
                    id));
}
```

Output:

```
vertex #0 (0) --> 
vertex #1 (6) --> vertex #7 (6) 
vertex #2 (3) --> 
vertex #3 (2) --> vertex #4 (4) vertex #5 (2) 
vertex #4 (4) --> vertex #6 (4) 
vertex #5 (2) --> 
vertex #6 (4) --> 
vertex #7 (6) -->
```

## CAUTION

Consider this an answer to the question *"I also wanted to know, is something above mentioned possible in a DAG using boost."*. Don't turn this in as your solution.

I deliberately wrote this solution with some flair and brevity. It **will** help you get something started, but please make sure you understand every step of the way. In fact, rewrite it using proper [bundled properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html), proper vertex id mapping, proper output etc.

Caveat emptor. Your education is your own responsibility. Learning is the greatest skill of them all.

### BONUS: Visualize

Using graphviz and filtering the zero vertex:

```
struct NotZero { bool operator()(V vd) const { return 0 != vd; } };
using F = boost::filtered_graph<G, boost::keep_all, NotZero>;

boost::dynamic_properties dp;
dp.property("node_id", id);
dp.property("shape", boost::make_constant_property<V>(std::string("Mrecord")));
dp.property("label", label);

write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, F(g, {}, {}), dp);
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c8fef6dac53c563)</kbd>**

[image]

Comment: Added bonus visualization.

Comment: Hey I got to know the problem for the error. std::cref and std::ref is not supported by old compilers as they are added recently in c++11.... so may i know if I can use any other function ??

Comment: If your compiler handles the code, it **does** handle c++11, the code is completely steeped in c++11 features. Apparently [your standard library doesn't implement `reference_wrapper` fully](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator()). Ironically, `boost::reference_wrapper<>` [never had that feature](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/core/doc/html/boost/reference_wrapper.html) so the logical idea of `boost::cref(getter)` falls flat. Now, I'd accept the limitations, and write the less efficient: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3252e9eb9e2076f